# Typedef function inside a class

Tags: c++, function, class, typedef, stdcall

I want to to be able to have my typedef function inside a class. But i dont find a way to do that. I need to scan for the address so i cant hardcode it in, therfor i need to sett the address like this `SetCursorPosFunction = (_SetCursorPos)(address to function);`

example:

```
class Cursor
{
public:

    typedef BOOL(__stdcall *_SetCursorPos) (int X, int Y);
    _SetCursorPos SetCursorPosFunction;
};
```

I want to be able to call the function like this `Cursor::SetCursorPosFunction(x,y)`

Example of what i mean.

```
void Function()
{
    DWORD_PTR AddressToFunctionSetCourserPos = Find(....);
    Cursor::SetCursorPosFunction = (Cursor::_SetCursorPos)(AddressToFunctionSetCourserPos ); //In final version it is going to be in a separate function where i get all the functions i need (This find() function can not be looped or called often, it is going to create lag etc.).

    Cursor::SetCursorPosFunction(1, 1);

}
```

I get the errors:

```
fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static int (__cdecl* Cursor::SetCursorPosFunction)(int,int)" (?SetCursorPosFunction@Cursor@@2P6AHHH@ZEA)
```

Comment: Why not use a `static` function member?

Comment: What's wrong with your current approach?

Comment: @PasserBy I ame not able to sett the address and call the function.

Comment: Can you show the specific code you wrote and the error you get? Do you want instead static members?

Comment: @PasserBy See updated thread :) Thank you for talking your time to answer. :)

Comment: Cool balls increases productivity [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spermatogenesis#Influencing_factors) +1 for your nickname

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modifying the function to a `static` will allow you to use it without have to instantiate a member first as you like:

```
class Cursor
{
public:
    typedef BOOL(__stdcall *_SetCursorPos) (int X, int Y);
    static _SetCursorPos SetCursorPosFunction;
};
```

`Cursor::SetCursorPosFunction(x,y)` should now work (given you initialize it first).

You also need to initialize the static member in global space. Something like `Cursor::_SetCursorPos Cursor::SetCursorPosFunction = nullptr;` should work. But be careful to have it in only one translation unit.

Comment: Yeah, it is like that i want it, but i get some errors. Maybe i initialize it wrong? Please see updated threade for error messages. :) Thank you for taking your time to answer :D

Comment: @ILikeMyBallsWarm You need to initialize all static members in global space. I kind of dislike this fact about C++, but you have to do it anyway.

Comment: yep, that was my problem :D Thanks :D Have a nice day and keep rocking.

PS.
It should be Cursor::_SetCursorPos Cursor::SetCursorPosFunction = nullptr;

Answer (score 3):

If you intended to emulate a member function you should create an instance of the cursor before trying to use it:

```
Cursor cursor;
cursor.SetCursorPosFunction(x, y);
```

You can also add a constructor to your class to initialize the pointer:

```
class Cursor
{
public:
    Cursor()
        : SetCursorPosFunction((_SetCursorPos) GetProcAddress(...))
    { }
    typedef BOOL(__stdcall *_SetCursorPos) (int X, int Y);
    const _SetCursorPos SetCursorPosFunction;
};
```